# Ionic 4 prevent shorten the class names for prod build

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, webpack, ionic4

I am building an ionic 4 app and using class names references in the local offline pouch DB it works fine. But when I make the Prod build with optimization true it shortens the classes to single alphabet name -

`e extends i.a { constructor(){super(),this.isActive=!0 }}`

I have used custom-webpack for keeping the class name with the following code -

```
module.exports = cfg => {
    const options = cfg.optimization.minimizer[cfg.optimization.minimizer.length - 1].options.terserOptions;
    if (options) {
        options.keep_classnames = true;
    }
    return cfg;
};
```

It works fine for `ionic serve --configration prod`

but not for `ionic build --configuration prod`

I want to keep class names for `ionic build --configration prod` with `optimization:true`.

Please help thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the TerserWebpackPlugin to keep the class names.

```
module.exports = {
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        terserOptions: {
          keep_classnames: true,
          keep_fnames: true,
        },
      }),
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: if I change `buildOptimizer: false` from `true` then it works fine.